# What is the CV model of LightGBM (lgb.cv) and how exactly do I use it?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, lightgbm

I am able to train a lgmb model using lgb.train and I can do the same with the CV model.

However, I can atleast use the train model for predictions, I am not sure how to understand what the lgb.cv returns.

Answer (score 1):

Check the official documentation [here](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python-API.html#lightgbm.cv)

Specifically, the returned value is the following:

> **Returns**:
>
> eval_hist – Evaluation history. The dictionary has the
> following format: {‘metric1-mean’: [values], ‘metric1-stdv’: [values],
> ‘metric2-mean’: [values], ‘metric2-stdv’: [values], …}.
>
> **Return type**:
>
> dict

A very similar topic is discussed here: [Cross-validation in LightGBM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46456381/cross-validation-in-lightgbm?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)